# semantic ui customize allowAdditions message

Tags: jquery, semantic-ui

Is there a possibility to customize the message of ***dropdown allowAdditions***?
By default is just **"add"**. But I want to give the user some template for the input, like **"add (first and last name):"**.

```
    $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('setting', {
       allowAdditions: true,
       action: 'combo'
    });
```

Here is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/xnjfzpw5/

Any help with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

semantic.js defines several default messages.
You may search the library for ***"message: {"*** ;-)

To customize the message , you could override the default message. But actually better to use the settings, like:

```
$('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('setting', {
    allowAdditions: true,
    message: {addResult:'Here your customized message: <b>{term}</b>'},
    action: 'combo'
  });
```

See the [modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vqgo3qga/) 
and have a nice day!

Comment: Worked well! Thank you!